# Titled border Tkinter - did not appear

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

i have this code, but this is only a part of a very long code for a system. the problem is, i tried to create a titled border but it does not appear. i do not know what is the mistake.

```
from Tkinter import *
def onclick():
    pass

import tkMessageBox


root = Tk()

root.title("Pantai Hospital")
root.geometry("200x200")

Label(root, text = "Welcome to Pantai Hospital!").grid()

#the problem starts here
f1 = Frame(root, width = 300, height = 110)
f2 = Frame(f1, relief = GROOVE, borderwidth = 2) 


l9 = Label(f2, text = "Choose your specialist:")
l9.pack(pady = 10)

specialistchoose = IntVar()
r1 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Cardiology", variable = specialistchoose, value = 1)
r1.grid(row = 1, column = 0 ) 
r2 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Gastroenterology", variable = specialistchoose, value = 2)
r2.grid(row = 1, column = 1) 
r3 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Dermatology", variable = specialistchoose, value = 3)
r3.grid (row = 1, column = 2)
r4 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Psychiatry", variable = specialistchoose, value = 4)
r4.grid (row = 3, column = 0)
r5 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Dentist", variable = specialistchoose, value = 5)
r5.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
f2.place(relx = 0.01, rely = 0.125, anchor = NW)
Label(f1, text = "Specialist:").place(relx = .06, rely = 0.125, anchor = W)
f1.pack() 
root.mainloop()
```

does anyone have any idea how to fx this? thank you :)

Comment: can you create image with expected result ?

Comment: I run your code and I got error message. Next time check your code in console/terminal/cmd.exe and add full error message in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is because you mix `grid()` and `pack()` and you get error message.

Don't use `grid()` and `pack()` in the same `Frame` (or `Window`). But you can still use `grid()` in one `Frame` and `pack()` in another `Frame` (another frame can be even inside first frame).

So try do it again.

---

**EDIT:** There is `LabelFrame` which draws `border` and `title`. You can use it instead of `Frame` and `Label`.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Pantai Hospital")

# in main window I use only `pack`

l = Label(root, text="Welcome to Pantai Hospital!")
l.pack()

lf = LabelFrame(root, text="Specialist:") 
lf.pack()

# inside LabelFrame I use only `grid`

t = Label(lf, text="Choose your specialist:")
t.grid(columnspan=2, stick='w')

specialistchoose = IntVar()

r1 = Radiobutton(lf, text="Cardiology", variable=specialistchoose, value=1)
r1.grid(row=1, column=0, stick='w') 

r2 = Radiobutton(lf, text="Gastroenterology", variable=specialistchoose, value=2)
r2.grid(row=1, column=1, stick='w') 

r3 = Radiobutton(lf, text="Dermatology", variable=specialistchoose, value=3)
r3.grid(row=1, column=2, stick='w')

r4 = Radiobutton(lf, text="Psychiatry", variable=specialistchoose, value=4)
r4.grid(row=2, column=0, stick='w')

r5 = Radiobutton(lf, text="Dentist", variable=specialistchoose, value=5)
r5.grid(row=2, column=1, stick='w')


root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: there were no error message. but i got it now. thank you very much! i appreciate it :)